# Method signature Haskell user defined type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying learning Haskell and I ended up reading [this](http://5outh.blogspot.it/2013/05/symbolic-calculus-in-haskell.html)
and I'm trying to figure out what some parts of the code do.

At first, there's a data type definition:

```
infixl 4 :+:
infixl 5 :*:, :/:
infixr 6 :^:

data Expr a = Var Char
             | Const a 
             | (Expr a) :+: (Expr a) 
             | (Expr a) :*: (Expr a)
             | (Expr a) :^: (Expr a)
             | (Expr a) :/: (Expr a)
             deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and next there is a function:

```
simplify :: (Num a, Eq a, Floating a) => Expr a -> Expr a
simplify (Const a :+: Const b) = Const (a + b)
simplify (a       :+: Const 0) = simplify a
simplify (Const 0 :+: a      ) = simplify a
```

So, what does "(Num a, Eq a, Floating a) => Expr a" stand for in this case?

"Expr" is not a constructor, and in the first line the type is "+ (Expr Expr)", so what does "a" mean here, and why is it restricted to be a double?
And is the "a" in the type signature related to the "a" in the second line of the function, even if here a is clearly an Expr?

Comment: I see no "`+ (Expr Expr)`" anywhere. What are you referring to? BTW, `Expr a` is a type, whose constructors are `Var, Const, (:+:), (:*:), (:^:), (:/:)`, the last ones being used in infix notation.

Comment: A few terms to help you understand: `Expr` is a *type constructor* because it constructs a type from the *type variable* `a`. `Expr` has the *kind* `* -> *` because it takes one normal data type (of kind `*`) and gives back another normal data type (of kind `*`). `Var`, `Const`, `:+:`, et al are *data constructor*s because they construct `Expr a`s from whatever their arguments are. Note that `Var :: Char -> Expr a`, `Const :: a -> Expr a`, `(:+:) :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In the data definition

```
data Expr a = ...
```

The `a` means that there is a type variable there.  A simple example would be

```
data Two a = Two a a
```

This is a type with the name `Two`, which takes a single type parameter.  It has a data constructor also called `Two` which has two fields, each of type `a`.  For example, the type `Two Int` has the specialized constructor `Two :: Int -> Int -> Two Int`

In this case, you're saying that your `Expr` type has a type parameter, and has a number of constructors, some of which have fields of type `a`.  You might use this to have a value of type `Expr Int`, such as `Const 1 :+: Const 2`.

When you see a type signature like

```
simplify :: (Num a, Eq a, Floating a) => Expr a -> Expr a
```

This means that the function takes a value of type `Expr a` and returns a value of the same type, except here the type variable `a` has additional constraints.  Namely `Num`, `Eq`, and `Floating`.  These are typeclasses, and a type `a` must implement those type classes for you to be able to use `simplify` on `Expr a`.

The `a` in the type signature has nothing to do with the `a` in the first line of the definition of `simplify`.  It's just a choice by the author to use the same name.  Type names and data names live in completely different namespaces in Haskell, they don't conflict or relate at all.

Answer (score 1):

For each type `a` that has instances for the typeclasses `Num`, `Eq` and `Floating`, `simplify` can specialize to `Expr a -> Expr a`. The namespaces of types and values are separate. `Expr` is a type constructor. `Expr a` is a type that has values. Nothing here is restricted to be a `Double`, `(+)` admits everything with a `Num` instance.